# richtextbox, embedding custom object

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rtf

I have a customized class which holds every move in chess and I want to write down every move to a richtextbox. So I am going to overload the tostring() of that custom class and use some formatting to add it to the rtf property of richtextbox. I need to find out which object is clicked so that I can set the game board accordingly. I don't know how to detect which object is clicked inside the richtextbox. Probabely I can use LinkClicked event of the richtextbox by introducing every object as a link to richtextbox. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer of your question - but using a ListBox, ListView, or other list control is not only much simpler, but will do everything you are asking and more (it's what they were designed for).

Comment: I need the formatting associated with the rtf. Some how may be I could use one of those but does not give me the UI I am looking for. Meanwhile I am using some special unicode characters that richtextbox will be a better option.

Comment: Your only two choices , then are to make each a hyperlink as you said, or to keep a table of object-to-character offsets and handle the click event